# IntelliJ "devices" window missing?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-13

There used to be a docked window showing current android devices (via usb or emulators) on the lower left corner along logcat but I guess I accidentally clicked close and now I can't bring it back. I don't even know how is it called and I've searched long enough for it to finally give up.

How do I bring it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! There is a little green android icon in the far right corner of the "Android DDMS" with a tool tip "Restore devices view". Yey!